# ionic 2 typescript source map not created

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic2

I am trying to debug **Ionic 2** Application And I want to know how to include **souceMap** for every **typescript** file that maps to the **javascript** files.

But when I open the dev tools in Chrome there is no any **souceMap** file.

[image: Chrome-dev-tool-source-img]

Also, I enabled the **`"sourceMap":true`** in **tsconfig.json** file.
This is my **tsconfig.json** file

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "es2015"
    ],
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "types": [
      "jasmine"
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "atom": {
    "rewriteTsconfig": false
  }
}
```

After that, I tried changing the **ionic.config.json** according to this 
[sourcemaps not working for ionic 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37785134/sourcemaps-not-working-for-ionic-2). But it also did not work for me.

Does anyone know what is wrong?

Comment: are you getting any error while you run the application ?

Comment: no errors. App is working perfectly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

found the answer.

Still **.map** files are not generated. Because it is a bug see this [issue](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-app-scripts/issues/431). But now I can debug after adding this

```
"config":{

     "ionic_source_map":"source_map"
}
```

into **package.json** file. Now all the **.ts** files are shown in the debug mode.

Answer (score 2):

It has changed now to -

```
config: {
    ionic_bundler: "webpack",
    ionic_source_map_type: "#inline-source-map"
  }
```

Comment: where should we put this line of code? To the `package.json` or `tsconfig.json`? Thanks.